# Passed NSString always null

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsstring

I need to pass an `NSString` from one view to another. I do in my `first view controller`:

```
-(IBAction)btnCreate_click:(id)sender
{
    CreateMatchTableViewController *matcObj = [[CreateMatchTableViewController alloc]init];
    matcObj.createBtnPressed = @"pressed";

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

 }
```

`CreateMatchTableViewController` is my second view controller and `createBtnPressed` ia `NSString` object in second view controller.

In `viewDidLoad` of second view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   // MatchListViewController *obj = [[MatchListViewController alloc]init];

    NSString *stringFromFirstView = createBtnPressed;

    NSLog(@"check===>%@",stringFromFirstView);//...always null
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: Why do you expect that, if you create an instance of an object in btnCreate_click and assign a value to it, and then let the object pass out of scope (and be destroyed), the value will mysteriously materialize elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that in your first view controller you are creating a new instance of CreateMatchTableViewController. You do not want that because you have your CreateMatchTableViewController instance already in the tab bar controller...

Try something like this:

```
-(IBAction)btnCreate_click:(id)sender
{
    CreateMatchTableViewController *matcObj = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    matcObj.createBtnPressed = @"pressed";

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

}
```

EDIT

```
-(IBAction)btnCreate_click:(id)sender
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

    CreateMatchTableViewController *matcObj = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];// I put 0 assuming you have a CreateMatchTableViewController as the navigation controller's root view controller
    matcObj.createBtnPressed = @"pressed";

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

}
```

Comment: it is giving exception....Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setCreateBtnPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: If you have a navigation controller in that tab you have to access to that view controller within your navigation controller, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

on CreateMatchTableViewController write a method like following:

```
(void)setStringFromFirstViewController:(NSString*)str{
    NSString *stringFromFirstView = str;
    NSLog(@"check===>%@",stringFromFirstView);
}
```

Now on "first view controller" do the following:

```
-(IBAction)btnCreate_click:(id)sender{
    CreateMatchTableViewController *matcObj = [[CreateMatchTableViewController alloc]init];
    [matcObj setStringFromFirstViewController: @"pressed"];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
    NSString* a = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:createBtnPressed];
```

Comment: it is giving exception...Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'

Comment: is createBtnPressed property synthesized?